# Removing hair dye from wall

Tags: cleaning, home, paint

My girlfriend was dying her hair (the permanent kind) and ended up getting some on the wall. However, I didn't find out until it had completely dried and now soap and water is not enough to remove it.
Obviously I don't want to use anything that will damage the wall or paint, and It's not worth buying paint for the wall.

What is my best option for removing hair dye from my wall?

Comment: This isn't a was to REMOVE the dye from your wall, but you could always hang a picture over it or put a piece of furniture in front of it. Or, if the splatter pattern is interesting at all, you could just place an empty frame around it and call it "art".

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can see short of high-filler sealing primer and then paint might be to bleach the dye using peroxide bleach similar to what your girlfriend most likely used on her hair before the dye step.  Peroxide is a very powerful oxidizer, and will denature most dyes.  It's likely to damage the paint, however, so if you rent, you may as well just leave it as is -- it'll cost you the same from your damage deposit when you move out either way.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your property manager for a very small quantity of the paint used to paint your apartment. Provide a small jar. They should have it on hand.

Tell him or her what happened and that you would like to repair it with the correct color to preserve your security deposit.

Be sure and thank them.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you do the following steps:

1. Take a cello tape
2. Unroll it and paste it over the dye on wall
3. Press on the tape so that it firmly sticks on to dye part.
4. Leave it for 3-5 seconds
5. Then try pulling the tape back suddenly
6. For sure, the tape will remove the die part along with very light amount of paint.
7. You can repeat this until you are satisfied with the wall

Anyway, if you are not satisfied with cleaning the wall using powerful chemicals that do not lose paint, you will have to suffer some paint loss. Moreover, paint samples are available in today's market that costs only very less price, you can purchase that and paint the lost portions.